# contact form headers

Tags: templates

I have recently installed the capulus joomla template. On the contact-form page I want to remove the headers"Store Hours" as well as configure the "Lorem ipsum" text under the Contact Form header (Please see image below circled in red).
How do I achieve this task?
I can't seem to find and edit the pages that contain the circled text.
[image]

Comment: Without actually seeing the backend I would say look in Extensions > Modules and see if this content resides there are custom html modules. Also you can look under your menus and see what component those pages are pointed at, there may be language overrides for those pieces of text that are not in the database at all but in a component language file.

Answer (score 1):

I found both the string in the language file.

Go to

> root/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_noo_capulus.ini

Here you will see the language string

```
NOO_CAPULUS_COM_CONTACT_OTHER_INFORMATION="Store Hours"
NOO_CAPULUS_COM_CONTACT_FORM_LABEL="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt dolor et tristique bibendum. Aenean sollicitudin vitae dolor ut posuere."
```

Now edit this string or replace it.

Also you can use Language manager to override language keys instead of deleting or modifying original language file.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I would recommend suggesting the OP overrides the language string in the Joomla back-end, rather than editing the language file ;)

Comment: @Lodder I totally agree, I'll update my answer ;)